# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google\Cloud\Exception\ConflictException' with message

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

How I can remove this error? Anyone knows?

```
    Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google\Cloud\Exception\ConflictException' with message
   '{ "error": { "code": 409, "message": "too much contention on these datastore entities.       
  please try again. entity groups:[(app=s~test-154434, demo, 4564)]", "status": "ABORTED" } } '
  in C:\xampp\htdocs\folder_name\vendor\google\cloud\src\RequestWrapper.php:219
```

Comment: Did you look the error code up in https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/status-codes

Comment: Or here https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/errors

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes i had checked ....actually on button click,I call to method in which there is having some  php code and cloud database queries. When I click first time on button click it show this error but when i click 2nd time it runs successfully, no such type of error comes, I don't know why it is not working in first time and sorry, because code is large that's why I have't pasted my code. I am using MVC framework

Comment: @SukhpalSingh, perhaps you can simplify your code somewhat and share it? It's very hard to determine why you're encountering errors without any code to look at. Generally, conflicts will arise if multiple transactions attempt to modify the same entities simultaneously. I'd check for that. While it's not implemented in the client currently, if you are using transactions, you should look into retrying aborted transactions.

Answer (score 0):

To answer this generally, without knowing the specifics, "contention" is a status that an [entity group](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/entities#Python_Transactions_and_entity_groups) enters when it has pending updates. Every requested update to an entity group is serialized, and then added to a queue. Requests for updates that last longer than a timeout are returned with that 409 status and removed from the queue.

[Google has recommendations for avoiding contention](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/scaling/contention) which basically boil down to some design principles: Keep entity groups small, avoid updating entity groups in rapid succession when possible, and make use of sharding when it isn't possible (which, in this context, typically means splitting a single entity into multiple entities that are chosen between randomly for writes, then aggregated for reads). The link has more specifics.